# Julia: view of sparse matrix

Tags: performance, julia, sparse-matrix, benchmarking

I am rather confused by how `view` acts on sparse matrices in Julia:

```
using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays, BenchmarkTools
v = SparseVector(1000, [212,554,873], [.3, .4, .3]);
A = sparse(diagm(rand(1000)));  # same effect observed for non-diag matrix
B = view(A, :, :);

julia> @btime A*v;
  1.536 μs (4 allocations: 23.84 KiB)

julia> @btime B*v;
  11.557 ms (5 allocations: 288 bytes)
```

`B*v` seems to have much lower memory footprint but is 8000x slower than `A*v`.
What is going on and what causes these performance differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update June 2021**: The missing specialized algorithm for sparse views mentioned below is now implemented, so the performance is *much* more reasonable these days (Julia 1.6+):

```
julia> @btime A*v;
  2.063 μs (4 allocations: 23.84 KiB)

julia> @btime B*v;
  2.836 μs (9 allocations: 25.30 KiB)
```

And you can see that, yes, indeed, this is using a sparse specialization for `*`:

```
julia> @which B*v
*(A::Union{SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, SubArray{Tv, 2, var"#s832", Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, I}, L} where {I<:AbstractUnitRange, var"#s832"<:SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, L}, LowerTriangular{Tv, var"#s831"} where var"#s831"<:Union{SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, SubArray{Tv, 2, var"#s832", Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, I}, L} where {I<:AbstractUnitRange, var"#s832"<:SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, L}}, UpperTriangular{Tv, var"#s832"} where var"#s832"<:Union{SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, SubArray{Tv, 2, var"#s832", Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, I}, L} where {I<:AbstractUnitRange, var"#s832"<:SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti}, L}}} where {Tv, Ti}, B::AbstractSparseVector{Tv, Ti} where {Tv, Ti}) in SparseArrays at /Users/mbauman/Julia/release-1.6/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/SparseArrays/src/linalg.jl:163
```

Previously, that method wasn't implemented, meaning that the below occurred:

---

**Old answer**: It's not 8x slower, it's *8000x* slower.  The reason is because Julia uses multiple dispatch to use specialized algorithms that can exploit the sparse storage of the matrix and vector to *completely avoid* working on sections of the array it knows will just be zero.  You can see which algorithm is getting called with `@which`:

```
julia> @which A*v
*(A::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC, x::AbstractSparseArray{Tv,Ti,1} where Ti where Tv) in SparseArrays at /Users/mbauman/Julia/master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/SparseArrays/src/sparsevector.jl:1722

julia> @which B*v
*(A::AbstractArray{T,2}, x::AbstractArray{S,1}) where {T, S} in LinearAlgebra at /Users/mbauman/Julia/master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:50
```

The former is using a highly specialized sparse implementation, whereas the latter is using a slightly more general interface that can also support views.  Now, ideally we'd detect the trivial cases like `view(A, :, :)` and specialize those to effectively be the same, too, but note that in general views may not preserve the sparsity and structure of the matrix:

```
julia> view(A, ones(Int, 1000), ones(Int, 1000))
1000×1000 view(::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  …  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  …  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) with eltype Float64:
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  …  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159     0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159     0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
 ⋮                                       ⋱
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159     0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159     0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
 0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159  …  0.306159  0.306159  0.306159
```

Comment: Ok, I see the point of general views not necessarily being sparse. So is the "solution" to just avoid using `view` on sparse matrices? Or is there a sparse alternative? I was hoping for something like `sparseview` or `view(A, sparse=true)`.

Comment: Updated the question to 8000x, was just a typo

Comment: The solution is to get specialized methods for views into sparse matrices https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21796 Though I'm really surprised that something as basic as matrix multiplication doesn't have a specialized method already